# java.lang.String cannot be converted to char

Tags: java

I'm a newbie and this is my first time trying to input char. I've written the following program to input grade and display result:
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Grade

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {


     System.out.println("Enter grade(A/B/C/D/E/F): ");
            char grade = obj.next(".").charAt(0);
            switch(grade)
           {
               case "A": //The error is displayed here in "A"
               System.out.println("Excellent");
               break;
               case "B": case "C":
               System.out.println("Well done");
               break;
               case "D": case "E":
               System.out.println("You passed");
               break;
               case "F":
               System.out.println("Better try");
               break;
               default:
               System.out.println("Invalid");
               break;
           }
           System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ");
           char cont = obj.nextChar();
        }
        while (cont == y);
    }
}
```

When I compile it, it highlights "A" and says java.lang.String cannot be converted into char. What should I do?

Comment: You're switching on a `char` and matching on a `String`. See the linked question.

Comment: Okay, so now I replaced the "A"  by just A but it still says cannot find variable A. I want the user to input the value A and match it to the case.

Comment: No, that is not what you must do, please go over the linked question again. It's neither `"A"` nor `A`.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry to bother and Thank you.